# duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 : Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

[image]
Not able to run the simple c++ program. 
Kindly help me to solve the problem

Comment: Do not post your code as images. Please post your code directly in the question as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message means that you have loaded same functions twice.
What is in hw.cpp? It will also be compiled and linked. If it is another main function that would be the cause. I suspect this is so since you only have one function.

Comment: Thank you. Problem Got solved.